# Initialize an array in C without square brackets, malloc and calloc

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I was wondering if it was possible to initialize an array without square brackets, malloc or calloc. It's possible to alter and change values with calloc, why not without all this?

```
void initTab(int * tab, int size) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        *(tab + i) = sizeof(int);
    } 
}
```

This is only an example for editing values in arrays but it doesn't work if the array is not properly initialized.

I want to replace this:

```
int * tab = calloc(nb_elements,sizeof(int));
```

Without calloc.

Comment: There is no array in you code.

Comment: You can certainly assign values to an array with `*(p+i)=`, but that's not an "initialization" as described in the language spec.

Comment: XY problem? What do you want to accomplish? `malloc` does not initialize anything.

Comment: Is there a manual way to do a calloc then?

Comment: Like `malloc` and then `memset`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to code this:
`int * tab = calloc(nb_elements,sizeof(int));`
if you can do it with malloc, you should be able to do it with pointers only no?

Comment: [`int * tab`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855143/initialize-an-array-in-c-without-square-brackets-malloc-and-calloc#comment74746268_43855143) is not an array, but a  pointer.  So is the issue of arrays or pointers?

Comment: `int x ??( ??) = { 1,2,3};` initializes an array without `[]`, `malloc()`, `calloc()`, but it uses the archaic tri-graph.

Comment: That's the kind of answer I was looking for, thank you all for your help. Sorry if I was not very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly possible to use arrays without malloc and calloc because you can make the array be a local or global variable instead of dynamically allocating it.  But the syntax for declaring or defining an array always uses square brackets and I don't understand why you need to avoid that kind of syntax.  You can have functions that manipulate arrays through pointers, and those functions don't need to use square brackets (and your question has an example of such a function).

Comment: There is no guarantee there is a stack.